# Extra border div on Firefox but not in Safari or Chrome

Tags: css, firefox

I have this CSS problem. Some divs shows an extra border only in Firefox:

[image]

But on Safari and Chrome it looks good:

[image]

This is the css for the divs:

```
.div {
    color:#555555;
    font-size: 13pt;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin-bottom:-5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height:auto; display:inline-block; width:900px;
    border-top:solid 1px #e1e1e1;
    z-index: 90;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: please provide html too..

Comment: It's impossible to tell from those images what the extra border is. Please describe it (in your question, not in a comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is `display:inline-block;`, you make them inline. why? firefox seem to insert new lines, that's the space you see. is there a reason why you don't use `display: block`? (just not visible in your small screenshots)